# Merge dataframe cols and a row to specific index base on another dataframe column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Sorry If the headline isn't clear enough, i'll explain myself better with example:

```
dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['UniqueNum', 'B' ,'A'])
dataframe1['UniqueNum'] = ['1a','2b', '3c']
dataframe1['A'] = ['2','6', '7']
dataframe1['B'] = ['3','88', '23']
print dataframe1
dataframe2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['TestId', 'C' ,'D'])
dataframe2['TestId'] = ['1a','2b', '3c', '1a', '3c', '2b']
dataframe2['C'] = ['22','46', '47','22','46', '47']
dataframe2['D'] = ['13','88', '233','22','46', '47']
print dataframe2
```

print are:

```
>>> 
  UniqueNum   B  A
0        1a   3  2
1        2b  88  6
2        3c  23  7
  TestId   C    D
0     1a  22   13
1     2b  46   88
2     3c  47  233
3     1a  22   22
4     3c  46   46
5     2b  47   47
>>>
```

I want to merge so the output dataframe will look like that:

```
      TestId   C    D   B  A
0     1a       22   13   3  2
1     2b       46   88  88  6
2     3c       47  233  23  7
3     1a       22   22   3  2
4     3c       46   46  23  7
5     2b       47   47  88  6
```

Meaning to add to dataframe2 the columns with the values correspond to the match between UniqueNum in dataframe1 to TestId in dataframe2.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and `rename` columns:

```
d = {'UniqueNum':'TestId'}
df = dataframe2.merge(dataframe1.rename(columns=d), how='left', on='TestId')
```

Or created index instead `rename` and change parameters for `left_on` and `right_index`:

```
df = dataframe2.merge(dataframe1.set_index('UniqueNum'), 
                      how='left', 
                      left_on='TestId', 
                      right_index=True)
```

Or specified both columns and last remove `UniqueNum` column:

```
df = dataframe2.merge(dataframe1, 
                      how='left', 
                      left_on='TestId', 
                      right_on='UniqueNum').drop('UniqueNum', axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)

  TestId   C    D   B  A
0     1a  22   13   3  2
1     2b  46   88  88  6
2     3c  47  233  23  7
3     1a  22   22   3  2
4     3c  46   46  23  7
5     2b  47   47  88  6
```